# How to specify GraphQL server location in Relay?

Tags: relayjs

I have successfully set everything up but unfortunately my GraphQL endpoint is not at the same location as the website that serves the client side.

I know this because in the error console of the browser it says :

`http://localhost:3000/graphql Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

three times then give up.

The page that I am using Relay is indeed at `http://localhost:3000/` but my GraphQL endpoint is at `http://localhost:5000/graphql`. Looks like it uses the current URL then automatically append `/graphql` to it. How can I instruct Relay to get data from other place?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it. (https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-network-layer.html)

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://example.com/graphql')
);
```

And just in case you are running this on `localhost` it is still subjected to CORS because it is on different port. In my case I am using an Express server for GraphQL endpoint so I used `cors` middleware to whitelist my other page.